# «Так что все в сад» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Запятая, тире или нет знака? Как правильно записать?

***Так что**, все в сад.

**Так что**, все — в сад.

**Так что** все в сад.*

Answer (score 2):

• ***Так что все в сад*.** [без пауз]

Думаю, что это эллиптическое предложение: в нем имеется подлежащее (*все*) и обстоятельство (*в сад*; куда?), сказуемое отсутствует (и мы не можем сказать, какое именно сказуемое пропущено, можем только предполагать — *идите, бегите, отправляйтесь, перемещайтесь*...).

[**так что**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/690/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)
**1.** Союз. То же, что «и поэтому», «следовательно». Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «так что», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). При этом первый знак препинания ставится перед союзом (перед словом «так»), а не между чего частями.
*На другой день по их приезде пошел проливной дождь, и ночью потекло в коридоре и в детской, **так что** кроватки перенесли в гостиную* (Л. Толстой. Анна Каренина).
**2.** Местоимение + союз. Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «что» выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми).
*Жизнь Берлиоза складывалась **так, что** к необыкновенным явлениям он не привык* (М. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита).

•• ***Так что все — в сад.***
В таких предложениях интонационное тире обычно ставится при наличии паузы в устной речи.

> В Белорецке много хороших спортивных секций, в которых ребята занимаются и достигают неплохих результатов. Это круто! **Так что все – в спорт!**

••• ***Так что — все в сад.***
Если же в тексте надо сделать паузу после "так что", то необходимо поставить тире, а не запятую.

> Бег, ролики, лыжероллеры, лыжная имитация с палками, велосипед, силовые тренировки — именно так лыжники проводят тёплый сезон. **Так что — все в парк!**

[Интонационное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94) (Розенталь)
[Неполные предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Тире после союза?  А это как, по каким правилам?  В эллиптическом предложении  ставится тире (и не только в лозунгах), но обычно между подлежащим и дополнением/обстоятельством. (Здесь,  кстати, не было восклицательного знака, интонация может быть нейтральной.)  Но тогда корректно: Так что все – в сад.  Так и детям можно сказать. Но объяснить тире после союза сложно.  Такое оформление возможно, но нужно другое объяснение. А если интонация нейтральная, но меньшую паузу и запятой можно обозначить, а не только тире.

Answer (score 1):

Оба знака излишни. *Так что* — союз, а не вводное слово, так что запятая после него излишняя.

**Так что все в сад.**

Comment: А тире можно ставить?

Comment: Вообще, если честно, мне кажется, что можно, если стоит пауза. А если ее нет, тире излишне

Comment: Интонационное тире именно так и ставится. Значит, тире можно поставить? А если я сделаю паузу после ТАК ЧТО и захочу ее как-то обозначить, то можно поставить какой-нибудь знак? Это интонационная и поэтому нестандартная задача.

Comment: Кстати, здесь и грамматическую основу надо определить.  Если я буду отвечать на этот вопрос, то позже. а вы подумайте, может, что исправите.

Answer (score 1):

**Теория**

1. Это **эллиптическое** предложение вида "подлежащее — обстоятельство",  союз ТАК ЧТО в значении **присоединительного** союза.

**[По Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93)** эллиптические предложения **обособляются**, если нет паузы. В то же время при отсутствии паузы **необособленный** вариант возможен.

**Интонация** предложения нейтральная, восклицательного знака нет. Поэтому это не призыв и не лозунг.

2. Можно ли **обособить** союз ТАК ЧТО? В текстах такой вариант встречается, но как его **объяснить**?

Союз «так что» синонимичен вводному слову ***«следовательно»***, поэтому его можно использовать **в значении** вводного слова.  (Стоит вспомнить, что вводное слово — это не часть речи, а грамматическая функция.) Вводное слово в начале предложения можно обособить **запятой или тире.**

**Решение задачи**

***Так что, все в сад.*** Союз ТАК ЧТО в значении вводного слова, эллиптическое предложение без тире.

Так что, все — в сад. Замена: ***Так что все — в сад.*** Тире в эллиптическом предложении  (две паузы делать неудобно).

***Так что все в сад.*** Эллиптическое предложение без паузы и тире.